# retrieving text from a column in Lua pinfo

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm using **Wireshark 1.8.2** and **Lua 5.1** --

Is there a way to retrieve the text from one of the **pinfo.cols** Columns?  I don't see a `get()` complement to the `set()` function, and if I just do something like `message(pinfo.cols.protocol)` or `message(tostring(pinfo.cols.protocol))`, it always just prints **protocol**... not the actual text string at that location.

I've got a pretty straightforward dissector I'm building for **IEEE802a OUI Extended Ethertype** frames.
  The problem is, in one branch of my code I can set the text in the protocol and info columns just fine.  In the other branch, those columns keep getting over-written with **Ethernet** and **Ethernet II** *after* my dissector has been called.  That's what I'm trying to track down...